# How to implement a safeReadFile function yielding Maybe String in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, exception, io, monads

I am trying to implement a safe `loadFile` function in Haskell which catches any exception and yields a `Maybe String` but the following implementation does not compile

```
 import System.IO         (readFile)
 import Control.Exception (catch, IOException)

 -- readFile :: FilePath -> IO String

 -- this compiles good
 safeReadFile :: FilePath -> IO (Either IOException String)
 safeReadFile p =
    (Right <$> readFile p) `catch`
    (\e -> pure $ Left e)

 -- this does not!
 safeReadFile' :: FilePath -> IO (Maybe String)
 safeReadFile' p =
    (Just <$> readFile p) `catch` 
    (\e -> pure Nothing)
```

Can anybody explain why the GCH is raising the following issue, please?

```
  Ambiguous type variable ‘e0’ arising from a use of ‘catch’
  prevents the constraint ‘(GHC.Exception.Exception
                              e0)’ from being solved.
  Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘e0’ should be.
  These potential instances exist:
    instance GHC.Exception.Exception IOException
      -- Defined in ‘GHC.IO.Exception’
    ...plus 20 instances involving out-of-scope types
    (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
```

How can I apply the necessary type annotation on the `e` variable? Haskell document doesn't give any clues :-(

Answer (score 5):

You have to specify which exception type you want to catch. `safeLoadFile` explicitly mentions `IOException`, while `safeLoadFile'` does not.

Try this instead:

```
safeLoadFile' :: FilePath -> IO (Maybe String)
safeLoadFile' p =
    (Just <$> loadFile p) `catch` 
    ((\e -> pure Nothing) :: IOException -> IO (Maybe String))
```

Or find some similar way to annotate the type for variable `e`. For instance `(\ (e :: IOException) -> ...)` can be also used, if you turn on `ScopedTypeVariables`.

Yet another alternative:

```
safeLoadFile' :: FilePath -> IO (Maybe String)
safeLoadFile' p = (Just <$> loadFile p) `catch` handler
   where
   handler :: IOException -> IO (Maybe String)
   handler _ = pure Nothing
```

Comment: I usually use `(\e -> pure $ const Nothing (e :: IOException))`. I find it to be a little less cluttered than the alternatives.